# Accessing a .net core REST API from an outlook web addin using microsoft identity platform

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, outlook-web-addins, microsoft-identity-platform, microsoft-identity-web

I have a .net core web REST api (.net 6.0) which uses microsoft identity platform to authenticate and authorize user access from a frontend. That is working fine.

Authentication is configured like this:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"), subscribeToJwtBearerMiddlewareDiagnosticsEvents: true)
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
            .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftDownstreamGraph"))
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

The same API should now be consumed by an outlook add-in. I obtain an access token using the office.js *getAccessToken()* function. If I call the API using this token, I receive:

> Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The audience
> 'e1c50fba-abcd-4e63-9f54-xxxxxxxxxx' is invalid".

The AzureAD API registration for the add-in has the permission 'access_as_user' for the REST API.
My current guess is, that I have to use the on-behalf-of flow and the API needs to exchange the add-in token for an token that is allowed to use the REST API. Is this correct? Is there an easy way using Microsoft.Identity.Web to achiev this?

To my knowledge I should not return the exchanged access token to the add-in. So I would have to cache it inside the REST API and alter the the API request transparently such that it includes the correct token (obtained via obo flow). How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does this page help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins? It is a good starting point and provides guidance on how to properly use SSO flows.

Comment: I did use this resource to get where I'm now. Unfortunately, it just says 'pass the access token to server-side code'. The question focuses on using a single API to authenticate direct user requests (ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/web-api-quickstart?pivots=devlang-aspnet-core) and requests made via an bootstrap token from the add-in. The token exchange needs to be incorporated somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The access token that is returned from the call to getAccessToken grants the host Office application (Excel, Word, etc.) access to the add-in; that is, to the add-in's web application. So, the audience of the token is the ID of the add-in in AAD. If the REST APIs were part of the add-in's web app, then that token would work, but if the REST API is a different web app (with it's own domain and AAD ID) then you would get the invalid audience error. You can either use the [OBO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow) (On Behalf Of) flow or the [Auth Code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/authorization-code-flow) to get a token with the REST API's ID as the audience, or redesign things so the add-in's web app and the REST service are the same domain and AAD ID. The web app would be serving up both the pages/scripts for the add-in AND exposing the REST API.

Comment: And how can I do this in an asp net core web API? The API is using Microsoft.Identity.Web with Azure AD to authenticate the frontend user of the single page application.

Comment: I have now integrated the add-in into the API domain as I thought about doing that anyway. So I mark that as accepted answer. thank you